# Initializing a List<T> with an array and populating

Tags: c#

I thought I was being clever but I was wrong. So for a unit test I need a List of X quantity and some values in each of the items in the list. So I came up with this as a concise way of getting there.

```
List<PlanList> planList = new List<PlanList>(new PlanList[7]);
planList.ForEach(c => c.Description = "I'm a Description");
planList.ForEach(c => c.OrderPosition = 1);
```

It turns out however that I get a list of 7 null objects.

[image]

So I'm curious to what's happening but MORE importantly I'm just trying to quickly generate a List with 7 object that can all have the same values for my test.

Comment: You created an array with 7 elements.  As you can tell, you did not initialize the elements so they are all null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't create an object at each index of the array . I can't see any `new PlanList()`. So you created an array of Length 7 holding default values for Reference Type `PlanList` which is `NULL`

Your code should throw a `NullReferenceExpcetion` in the `ForEach` !

I Would do this:

```
List<PlanList> planList = (from index in Enumerable.Range(0, 7)
                            select new PlanList()
                            {
                                Description = "I'm a Description",
                                OrderPosition = index
                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: I think OP wants `OrderPosition = 1` instead of `OrderPosition = x`.

Comment: @S.Akbari He can change it, I thinking he couldn't have a counter in `ForEach` that's why he set all to 1. I was just showing that with Enumerable.Range you can have that.

Comment: OP said: *I'm just trying to quickly generate a List with 7 object that can all have the same values for my test*

Comment: So my OP did want just a one but I was wondering if instead I could have the index value so you intuitively answered my next ?

Comment: @GPGVM Yes, this is the way.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that you're looking for something like this:

```
List<PlanList> planList = Enumerable
  .Range(0, 7)
  .Select(index => new PlanList() {
     Description = "I'm a Description", 
     OrderPosition = 1 
   })
  .ToList();
```

i.e. *create* `7` `PlanList` instances and *materialize* them as list.

Answer (score 5):

<strike>I'm guessing that `PlanList` is a `struct` here, right? (no `new`, and values lost).</strike>

With a `struct`, when you fetch an item *from* the list, you have a **copy**. If you mutate the copy: the original does not know or care.

Basically, most of your problems should be fixed by making `PlanList` a `class`. It is very uncommon to create `struct`s in most regular C# code.

Note that you will need to *create the instances*. If it was me, I would just use (where `PlanList` is a `class`):

```
var list = new List<PlanList>();
for(int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++)
    list.Add(new PlanList { Description  = "foo", OrderPosition = 1});
```

Comment: Not a struct it is a class I just don't know the syntax to make it initialize like everyone is saying.

Comment: @GPGVM then your code should have exploded already with a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: @GPGVM but even so, the code shown above will instantiate them correctly

Comment: You are of course right. I blows up when it tries the foreach.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new array `new PlanList[7]`, all the elements inside the array will be initialized to the **default value** for that type (See [default keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx)). In your case, the **default value** for `PlanList` is `null`.

You'll have to initialize each element manually.

One way to do it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < planList.Count; i++)
   planList[i] = new PlanList();
```